# Row of an Ant Design table should be checkbox

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need a `checkbox` in all columns of a row in the Ant Design table. i.e in the given sandbox, the table should have 3 checkboxes instead of `John Brown`, `32` & `New York No. 1 Lake Park`. Please help me out.

Thank you.

Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bogdan-qwhes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-voice-vdtm4).

You are able to render whatever you want in column cell using [`render` prop of column](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) in Ant. So if you are able to put there function that render checkbox component.

If you want to control checkboxes, you need to set `checked` and `onChange` props according [checkbox API](https://ant.design/components/checkbox/#Checkbox). Here I used [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to use one function to handle at each checkbox.

Comment: Having similar situation, 2 columns with checkboxes but you can only select checkbox from one column in a row, how to disable checkbox in second one?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below:
You are not adding any functionality for selectedRowKeys, rowSelection.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Table } from 'antd';

const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  render: text => <a href="#">{text}</a>,
}, {
  title: 'Age',
  dataIndex: 'age',
}, {
  title: 'Address',
  dataIndex: 'address',
}];

const data = [{
  key: '1',
  name: 'John Brown',
  age: 32,
  address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: 42,
  address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '4',
  name: 'Disabled User',
  age: 99,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedRowKeys: [],
  };
  selectRow = (record) => {
    const selectedRowKeys = [...this.state.selectedRowKeys];
    if (selectedRowKeys.indexOf(record.key) >= 0) {
      selectedRowKeys.splice(selectedRowKeys.indexOf(record.key), 1);
    } else {
      selectedRowKeys.push(record.key);
    }
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
  }
  onSelectedRowKeysChange = (selectedRowKeys) => {
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedRowKeys } = this.state;
    const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys,
      onChange: this.onSelectedRowKeysChange,
    };
    return (
      <Table
        rowSelection={rowSelection}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        onRow={(record) => ({
          onClick: () => {
            this.selectRow(record);
          },
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.4.3/antd.min.js"></script>
```